# Modifying Apache config or .htaccess results in site timeout

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I'm trying to modify my Ubuntu 15.04 web server to do two things:

1. Secure the site whilst in development by using a .htpasswd file
2. Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS

For both of these tasks, when I modify either the .htaccess in my site's directory or the apache2.conf file, the site stops responding and gives a timeout error.

For problem 1 I've tried the following:

- create a password file using htpasswd
- In the main apache2.conf I have a Directory tag with the following:

  `<Directory /var/www/myfolder/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Auth"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile /var/www/passwords
      Require valid-user
  </Directory>`

So in the browser I get a connection timeout, and don't get a username/password box like I expect. In the apache error log I get a few lines like the following:

```
AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
```

For problem 2, I've tried the following in the apache2.conf Directory tag first, then in the .htaccess file in my directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I get the same timeout in the browser, and a different error in the apache log:

```
AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myfolder/
```

I can't see any difference in the config of this server and others I have, apart from this is using Ubuntu 15.04 rather than 14.04 that I've used in the past. Any ideas?